# Why are strings not same?

Tags: java, json

I would have assumed the test case below would have worked, but it does not.
Reason is that the string taken from JsonObject have replaced `"\"` with `"\\"`.

Is that a correct behavior and is there a safe work around?

```
@Test
public void stringTest()
{
    Path path = Paths.get("myFile.txt");

    JsonObject json =   Json.createObjectBuilder().add("path",path.toAbsolutePath().toString()).build();

    Assert.assertTrue(json.get("path").toString().contains(path.toAbsolutePath().toString()));
}
```

Comment: Please tag with the language and show the contents or the relevant part of myFile.txt.

Comment: I've tagged question with "Java". Content of "myFile.txt" is not relevant for my question.

Comment: Seems that the JSON ObjectBuilder masks the Backslash. So you can do
Assert.assertTrue(json.get("path").toString().contains(path.toAbsolutePath().toString().replaceAll("\\","\\\\"));

Comment: `get("path").toString()` probably is converting an Object instance to a string, and so it is likely not the string you inserted. What JSON library are you using and why use `contains` vs `equals`?

Comment: In other words, the backslashes are a side-effect of you converting an already valid JSON string into a Java string.

Comment: I am using javax.json and org.glassfish.json

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I needed some help to clear my mind. 
I used the library wrong.

If I changed the assert line from:

```
   json.get("path").toString().contains(...
```

to:

```
json.getString("path").equals(.....
```

it all works well.

//lg